# Agrupamiento en SQL por id específicos

Tags: sql, group-by, id

Si pudieran ayudarme con la siguiente consulta les agradecería.

Tengo la 1ra tabla que sería el juego de datos y necesito:

**agrupar los códigos 3, 4 y 5** en un solo código (y una nueva descripción), **por mes** para saber el **total del costo**

dando como resultado la 2da tabla

Muchas gracias de antemano.
Saludos

[image: juego de datos y salida requerida]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: Deberías poner algo que hayas realizado hasta el momento

Answer (score 2):

Bueno al parecer me di por vencido muy rápido pues después de 10 min de seguir buscando  aquí en **stackoverflow** encontré este link que me ayudó a resolver la sentencia SQL (que lo dejo por acá por si alguien la necesita).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815461/group-by-multiple-values-in-same-column

La idea fue hacer un **case when then** para crear subgrupos. Esto solo crea grupos de datos, entonces en la salida tenía que aplicar la misma lógica.

```
SELECT    
           mes
           ,case 
                when codigo ='01' or codigo ='02' then codigo    
                else 'nuevocodigo'                      
            end AS CODIGO                       
            ,case 
                 when codigo ='01' or codigo ='02' then descripcion                             
                 else 'NuevoTextoDescriptivo'
            end AS DESCRIPCION
            ,sum(costo) AS costo        
    FROM tabladata                                              
    GROUP BY 
            (case when codigo ='01' or codigo ='02' then codigo 
                  else 'nuevocodigo'                        
            end )       
            ,(case when codigo ='01' or codigo ='02' then descripcion                           
                   else 'NuevoTextoDescriptivo'
            end )
            ,mes        
    ORDER BY mes DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que quieres hacer es algo como esto:

```
SELECT tusDatos
FROM tuTabla
WHERE codigo BETWEEN 3 AND 5
GROUP BY codigo
```

Comment: esto (ademas que op no mostro ni un intento de hacer algo) no funciona.. por mas que pongas el where, si pones el group by, va a traer 3 filas.. una para cada codigo... sin importar que escribas en el select...

Comment: Entonces, ¿Con un `Union` podría solucionarse su problema, verdad?

Comment: Tampoco... es con un group by... pero no por donde vas vos.... igual, me gustaria que op intentara algo antes de poner una respuesta....

Comment: esta me exceptúa los demás códigos (1 y 2 quedan fuera de la condicion)